# AngularJS function inherit

Tags: angularjs, inheritance, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I have angular JS with 5 controllers and I want to all of the children inherit all functions of parent (datetimepicker, autorefresh etc.. that is predefined in parent controller) I tried with rootscope but didn't get solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can take common functionality into service/factory an use it in controllers

```
var app = angular.module('angular', []);

    app.factory("common",function(){
     return {};
    })

   app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope, $controller,common) {

    });
```

or you can inherit from a controller like this

```
var app = angular.module('angular', []);

    app.controller('ParentCtrl ', function($scope) {
      ctrl to act as parent
    });

    app.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope, $controller) {
      $controller('ParentCtrl', {$scope: $scope}); 
    });
```